# mono-symbolicate fails due to Xamarin.Droid stacktrace not including AotID

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.android, mono, xamarin.droid

I'm trying to use mono-symbolicate to symbolicate stack traces produced by the release version of our app. In the .csproj Release build settings DebugSymbols, Optimize, MonoSymbolArchive have all been set to True, and DebugType has been set to Full.

When building Release, it seems to successfully generate the msym folder `MyApp.Droid 7-13-18 3.35 PM.apkarchive/mSYM/com.myco.myapp.apk.mSYM` which contains many GUID-named folders, some containing a single .msym file and some containing both a .dll and .pdb file. As I can see in my stack trace, it seems my MyApp.Droid has been given the GUID `7216aaa9c1294991b8b2782974cfb879` and looking in the directory of the same name, I do indeed see MyApp.Droid.dll and MyApp.Droid.pdb. Browsing through the msym folder, I also find four other directories each containing a file called MyApp.Droid.msym, which I assume means it splits the msym up into several files for some reason.

Using the minimal stack trace

```
at MyApp.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) <0x7c92255fd8 + 0x0008b> in <bf44972100fb4c2b8f5abcae2e982c3f>:0
```

(or any more complete, longer stack trace for that matter) and running `mono-symbolicate path/to/MyApp.Droid 7-13-18 3.35 PM.apkarchive/mSYM/com.myco.myapp.apk.mSYM myStackTrace.txt`, the mono-symbolicate script crashes with the following error:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
  at Mono.SymbolManager.GetOrCreateSeqPointInfo (System.String aotid) [0x00057] in <e1e81dae0fc04bc2a59e1766bbba201f>:0 
  at Mono.SymbolManager.TryResolveLocation (Mono.StackFrameData sfData) [0x0002e] in <e1e81dae0fc04bc2a59e1766bbba201f>:0 
  at Mono.Symbolicate.SymbolicateAction (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] args) [0x00034] in <e1e81dae0fc04bc2a59e1766bbba201f>:0 
  at Mono.Symbolicate.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0017f] in <e1e81dae0fc04bc2a59e1766bbba201f>:0
```

Reading the source code of mono-symbolicate, it seems like it's failing due to trying to parse an aotid from the stack trace, which it does not seem to contain. My understanding is that this aotid would be a second part inside the last angular brackets, such as:

```
at MyApp.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) <0x7c92255fd8 + 0x0008b> in <bf44972100fb4c2b8f5abcae2e982c3f#4ed70d01848e11d51d01dac0cb2d805e>:0
```

where `4ed70d01848e11d51d01dac0cb2d805e` matches one of the folder names which include an MyApp.Droid.dll.msym file. Indeed, manually finding the folders which contain a MyApp.Droid.dll.msym and adding `#foldername` as a suffix in the angular brackets, I find one that works (does not produce a crash) after a few tries.

Why am I not getting the AOTIDs in the stacktrace, or how can I work around this?

Comment: Ran into the same issue, just curious if you found a solution? Also, do you have AotAssemblies set to true for your build?